# How to isolate handwritten digit candidates out of an image?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, deep-learning, python-imaging-library

I implemented a neural network that recognizes handwritten digits based on the [MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/). I am using bare python/numpy and now I want to test my own handwritten images against the network. I would however like to automate the cropping and scaling process, so that I can supply an image taken by a smartphone and get a mnist-format numpy array.

So far, I had *some* success, but I don't really know how to proceed from here.
These are two example images and below the respective masked images, which are a crop half the size of the original image to narrow the field of search down:

[image: image of a 4]
[image: image of a 7]

[image: Processed Image of a 4]
[image: Processed Image of a 7]

As you can see, there is something happening, but it is not satisfactory. I also would not know how to proceed  if i had segmented and masked the '4' and '7' perfectly. **How do you get the precise position so I can crop and downscale to 28x28 pixels?**

The code that produced those images looks as follows. It basically calculates a spatial histogram of the x and y pixelspace axes, and then blacks out everything that does not contain enough black for it to be something written.
plot() and hist() are just convenience functions, but do produce the image you see, so I included them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def hists(x, y):

    histx,_ = np.histogram(np.arange(len(x)), bins=len(x), weights=x)
    histy,_ = np.histogram(np.arange(len(y)), bins=len(y), weights=y)
    return histx, histy

def plot(ndimg):

    w, h = ndimg.shape

    x = np.mean(ndimg, axis=0)
    x -= np.mean(x)
    y = np.mean(ndimg, axis=1)
    y -= np.mean(y)

    nullfmt = NullFormatter()

    left, width = 0.1, 0.65*h/w if w > h else 0.65
    bottom, height = 0.1, 0.65*w/h if h > w else 0.65
    left_h = left + width + 0.02
    bottom_h = bottom + height + 0.02

    rect_img = [left, bottom, width, height]
    rect_histx = [left, bottom_h, width, 0.2]
    rect_histy = [left_h, bottom, 0.2, height]

    plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 8))

    axImg = plt.axes(rect_img)
    axHistx = plt.axes(rect_histx)
    axHisty = plt.axes(rect_histy)

    axHistx.xaxis.set_major_formatter(nullfmt)
    axHisty.yaxis.set_major_formatter(nullfmt)

    axImg.imshow(ndimg, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))

    axHistx.hist(np.arange(len(x)), bins=int(0.03*len(x)), weights=x)
    axHisty.hist(np.arange(len(y)), bins=int(0.03*len(y)), weights=y, 
                 orientation='horizontal')

    axHistx.set_xlim(axImg.get_xlim())
    axHisty.set_ylim(axImg.get_ylim())

    plt.show()

def mask(ndimg, bw_threshhold=0.6, mask_threshhold=5e-3):
    ndimg = ndimg / np.max(ndimg)
    ndimg = np.where(ndimg < bw_threshhold, 0.0, 1.0)
    #ndimg = np.exp(-np.logaddexp(0, -10*(ndimg-0.6)))

    x = np.mean(ndimg, axis=0)
    #x = x - np.mean(x)
    y = np.mean(ndimg, axis=1)
    #y = y - np.mean(y)

    histx, histy = hists(x, y)
    histx = histx - np.mean(histx)
    histy = histy - np.mean(histy)
    #histx -= (histx.max() + histx.min())/2
    #histy -= (histy.max() + histy.min())/2

    maskx = np.where(histx < mask_threshhold, False, True)
    masky = np.where(histy < mask_threshhold, False, True)

    ndimg[masky, :] = 0.
    ndimg[:, maskx] = 0.
    return ndimg

img = Image.open('C:/Users/maxid/Desktop/Pics/7_1.jpg')
                 .convert(mode='L')
w, h = img.size
img = img.crop((0.25*w, 0.25*h, 0.75*w, 0.75*h))
ndimg = np.asarray(img)
plot(ndimg)
ndimg = mask(ndimg, )
plot(ndimg)
a, b = hists(np.mean(ndimg, axis=0), np.mean(ndimg, axis=1))
print((a.max()+a.min())/2, np.mean(a), np.median(a))
plt.plot(a)
```

So, I would like to end up with a square image of the handwritten digit displayed approximately in the middle of the picture. For this it would probably be enough to get the middle of the digit, but I cannot think of an easy and semi-reliable (does not have to be production grade) way to do this.

Comment: you could use train an object detection network that finds the digits and classifies them

Comment: You could look at thresholding and finding contours. OpenCV is a good choice for such tasks.

Comment: @chris But for this I would need a fairly big dataset, which I do not have as MNIST is already cropped and in the right format.

Comment: @QuangHoang So by finding the contours of the digit i could tell where the middle is, but I do not only have digits in my unprocessed image. How can I discern between edged and digits?